# Tengo un problema para instalar Create React App en windows

Tags: reactjs

Estoy trabajando en windows 7 64bit . Quiero programar con Create React App. Lo trato de instalar por la terminal de comando pero me arroja errores que creo q son de permisos , no se si son de permisos o algo sobre un paquete o el core . No se que hacer para resolver eso !!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! yo ahi (capaz me equivoco) no veo ningun error... no se instala cuando tratas de correrlo???

Comment: en la imagen la instalación parece correcta.

Comment: Realmente ¿Cuál es la pregunta? En la imagen no veo ningún error. ¿Ya verifcaste que se te hayan creado la carpeta y los archivos adentro?

Comment: Ahi sale "63 packages are lucking for funding" creo que eso es parte del problema

Answer (score 0):

Primero limpia la cache con

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Actualiza la version con
npm install -g npm@next
Despues intenta crear nuevamente tu proyecto

Si siguies teniendo problema reinstala nuevamente Node

Answer (score 0):

Muchas Gracias , realice lo del limpiando de cache pero siguió igual. Lo solución que encontré fue descargando node para windows 32 bits . La versión  (v12.18.3-x86.msi) me funciono !!